# VBA: If A found in line 1, and B found in line 2.. then

Tags: vba, if-statement, readline

I currently have my VBA set up to read a text file (using `FileSystemObject`) and to find certain strings. This all works great. But what I am trying to achieve is for VBA to read through the text and when it finds a certain string (A) and in the next line below it another string (B) it will do something. But only if B is right after A.

Example:

```
Find in the following text "Bob's House" and in the next line after that "Electricity.
Text 1: - Return False
blablabla *Bob's House* blablabla
blablabla blablabla blablabla
blabla *Electiricity* blablabla

Text 1: - Return True
blablabla *Bob's House* blablabla
blabla *Electiricity* blablabla
```

This is what I have so far:

```
Set fsFile = fs.OpenTextFile(FilePath, 1, False)
sLine = fsFile.ReadLine

If VBA.InStr(1, sLine, "Bobs House") > 0 Then
   checkpointHeading = True
End If
If VBA.InStr(1, sLine, "Electricity") > 0 Then
   checkpointSubheading = True
End If
If checkpointHeading = True And checkpointSubheading = True Then
   MsgBox "Found it!"
End If
```

This returns "Found it" regardless of how many lines there are between `Bobs House` and `Electricity`. Which makes sense. But how do I force the second restraint only after the first is found the line before?

Is there something like `sLine +1` / `.Readline + 1` (and then apply the second if statement inside the first?).
Thanks in advance, R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having this trouble because you are not resetting the  'Bob's House' variable on the next line if that line doesn't equal 'Electricity'.  So once Bob's House is found it will always be true and it doesn't matter where 'Electricity' comes in.

You can accomplish what you are after one of two ways.  Using Booleans like you have and the code in 'Way 1' (which I've bloated out a bit so its easy to follow), or probably a better way where you simply set the current line string variable to a new string variable which holds the previous line at the end of the loop and then check both of these variables next line like in 'Way 2'.

(Note there are a couple of typos in your example which I've retained so the code works with the example).

```
    Sub Way1()
    Dim fs As New FileSystemObject, fsfile As Object
    Dim sLine As String
    Dim checkpointHeading As Boolean, checkpointSubheading As Boolean

    'Open file
    Set fsfile = fs.OpenTextFile("G:Test.txt", 1, False)

    'Loop through
    Do While fsfile.AtEndOfStream <> True

        sLine = fsfile.ReadLine

        If VBA.InStr(1, sLine, "Bob's House") > 0 Then
           checkpointHeading = True
        Else
           'If the line doesn't have Bob's House then check if the line before did
           If checkpointHeading Then
               'If it did then check for Electricity
               If VBA.InStr(1, sLine, "Electiricity") > 0 Then
                   'If it's found then happy days
                   checkpointSubheading = True
               Else
                   'If it's not found then reset everything
                   checkpointHeading = False: checkpointSubheading = False
               End If
           End If
        End If

        'Check if we've found it
        If checkpointHeading = True And checkpointSubheading = True Then
           MsgBox "Found it!"

           'You may want to reset here to be safe
           checkpointHeading = False:    checkpointSubheading = False
        End If

    Loop

    fsfile.Close
    Set fsfile = Nothing
    Set fs = Nothing
End Sub
```

The easier and more concise way 2:

```
Sub Way2()
    Dim fs As New FileSystemObject, fsfile As Object
    Dim sLine As String, sPrevLine As String

    'Open file
    Set fsfile = fs.OpenTextFile("G:Test.txt", 1, False)

    'Loop through
    Do While fsfile.AtEndOfStream <> True

        sLine = fsfile.ReadLine

        If VBA.Len(sPrevLine) > 0 Then
            If VBA.InStr(1, sPrevLine, "Bob's House") > 0 And VBA.InStr(1, sLine, "Electiricity") Then
                MsgBox "Found it!"
            End If
        End If

        'Set the current line to the previous line *at the end of the loop*
        sPrevLine = sLine
    Loop

    fsfile.Close
    Set fsfile = Nothing
    Set fs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I used the second method, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: No worries, thinking about it you can probably drop the `If VBA.Len(sPrevLine) > 0 Then` since the next line will return zero if the length is zero too.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it, but this should demonstrate the logic:

```
 Const filepath = "..."

 Sub test()

    Dim fs
    Dim fsFile
    Dim found As Boolean
    Dim flag As Boolean
    Dim sLine As String

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fsFile = fs.OpenTextFile(filepath, 1, False)

    found = False
    flag = False
    Do While Not fsFile.AtEndOfStream And Not found
        sLine = fsFile.readLine
        If flag And InStr(sLine, "Electricity") Then found = True
        flag = (InStr(sLine, "Bobs House") > 0)
    Loop

    If found Then
        MsgBox sLine
    Else
        MsgBox "not found"
    End If

 End Sub
```

Edit: Tested.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
    sLine = fsFile.ReadLine

    If isHeading Then
        If InStr(1, sLine, "Electricity") > 0 Then
            MsgBox "Found It!"
        End If
        isHeading = False
    End If

    If InStr(1, sLine, "Bobs House") > 0 Then
        isHeading = True
    End If
```